# SATA HDD Docking station write errors

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I own an old USB3-to-SATA dockstation like this https://www.dustinhome.se/product/5010646120/dock-station-2535-esatafwusb-30

The problem is that the docking station doesn't work well with Ubuntu 18.04. It's connected via USB 3. The disk shows up, but if I try to write something to the SATA disk, I get a

> Buffer I/O error on dev sdb3, logical block 121675008, lost async page write

from dmesg. In Windows 10 I don't have this problem.

I have searched if anyone has a solution, but I found nothing. I guess my SATA  docking station is an unusual type.

If anyone has any clue what I can do to troubleshot - please write a comment.

The `lsusb` output for the device:

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0525:3102 Netchip Technology, Inc.
```

The full `lsusb -v` output [can be found here at Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/bK5UZj40).

Comment: I tested to connect the docking station via an USB 2.0 hub and that works great. But I will be more happy if I can use it with USB 3.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Disable USB Attached SCSI (uas) for the device.

```
bash -c 'cat <<EOF >/etc/modprobe.d/ignore_uas.conf
options usb-storage quirks=0525:3102:u
EOF' | sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

Read more on [OpenSuse wiki](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:USB_3.0_Hard_Drive_troubleshooting)